# Uploading an updated version of app to the store with new app id

Tags: iphone

Our app is already there in app store. We now have integrated push notification support to our app and this requires new app id to be created, because our existing app id has got asterisk symbol in it. To enable push notification, app id should not have asterisk at the end, instead it has to have an unique name. So we decided to create a new app id which has got push notification enabled.

But if we do so, will we be able to upload our app as an update to our existing app which is there in the app store?, or our new submission will be considered as a new app? or what other problems we will be facing?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We've gone through similar issues, and I'd like to put a disclaimer here that we don't actually have anything released yet, but we were able to use the same bundle identifier with a new app-id and a new provisioning profile, and it did overwrite the old app on the phone that had the old version.

I don't *think* the changed app-id will make a difference  After all, if you have 10 different apps using the asterisk ID, they are still considered 10 different apps, so the app-id is probably more specific to the signing end.  The Bundle-id is what determines the app's identity on the device itself, and so I *think* it's the same in the app store.